# Reuse variable instead of new DOM search

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the menuBar object I've defined before to do a manipulation on objects within.

```
var menuBar = $(".menu-bar ul");
var menuActive = menuBar.find("li.active");
menuBar.hover(function(){
    menuActive.toggleClass("active");
});
$('.menu-bar ul > li > a[href="'+ window.location.href +'"]').parent().addClass("active");
```

What I do not like is to call the DOM search once more to define the active class for link parent.

Any thoughts on how to do it with menuBar variable?

Comment: So you don't want to call  `.parent()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
var menuBar = $(".menu-bar ul");
var menuActive = menuBar.find("li.active");
menuBar.hover(function(){
    menuActive.toggleClass("active");
});
$('li > a[href="'+ window.location.href +'"]',menuBar).parent().addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for:

```
menuBar.find('> li > a[href="'+ window.location.href +'"]').parent().addClass("active");
```

or really since you're trying to select the parent:

```
menuBar.find('> li:has(> a[href="'+ window.location.href +'"])').addClass("active");
```

The `:has` pseudo-class allows you to select an element which contains another element. That's really what you're going for, and you should allow the selector itself to do any optimizations it can.

Comment: I really like the has method! thanks Nathan, not a fan of find though

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a context to search within:

```
$('li > a[href="'+ window.location.href +'"]', menuBar.children()).parent().addClass("active");
```

Here `menuBar.children()` would be the context.